# 2 javascript functions using localStorage causing troubles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my visitors to choose between 4 background colors in light mode or to just turn dark mode on.

My first script changes the background color of BODY-tag without problem, but when using together with my second javascript to turn on dark mode it just causes problem and only dark/light mode works. I think there must be some kind of problem with the localstorage function but I am very new to Javascript and I really can not make them work.

Here is the HTML:

```
#// These divs changes the color of body in white/light mode

<div class="coeleste" onclick="setBackground('#ECF3F9')">Elegant</div>

<div class="viridis" onclick="setBackground('#F1F9EC')">Modern</div>
  
<div class="rubrum" onclick="setBackground('#F2EBDD')">Classic</div>

<div class="initialis" onclick="setBackground('#FFFFFF')">Default</div>

#// And this div changes the color of body to dark/light mode
  
<div class="luminaria"><a id="modus" href="#">TURN OFF THE LIGHTS</a></div>
```

Here is the javascript first part to change the color of body background in light mode. it is simple but it works alone

```
function setBackground(color) 
{
localStorage.setItem("name", color);
window.location.href = '#';  //reload the page to effect the change.
}
if(localStorage.name)   //Accessing name variable of localStorage.
{
document.body.style.background = localStorage.name;
}
```

And here is the function to set dark mode on/off, when working alone it works fine too, but when using the javascript from above and this one together then only this dark mode works but not the first one

```
//second javascript

var modus = document.getElementById("modus"),
  corpus = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
modus.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var o, s;
  corpus.classList.contains("luccious")
    ? (corpus.classList.remove("luccious"),
      (modus.textContent = "TURN OFF THE LIGHTS"),
      (o = "#FFFFFF"),
      (s = "#121212"))
    : (corpus.classList.add("luccious"),
      (modus.textContent = "TURN ON THE LIGHTS"),
      (o = "#121212"),
      (s = "#FFFFFF")),
    (corpus.style.backgroundColor = o),
    (corpus.style.color = s),
    localStorage.setItem("albus", o),
    localStorage.setItem("umbra", s);
});
var lux = localStorage.getItem("albus"),
  umbris = localStorage.getItem("umbra");
lux &&
  umbris &&
  ((corpus.style.backgroundColor = lux),
  (corpus.style.color = umbris),
  "#121212" === lux &&
    "#FFFFFF" === umbris &&
    (corpus.classList.add("luccious"),
    (modus.textContent = "TURN OFF THE LIGHTS")));
```

I created this Codepen to see it in action
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/VwVKzrq

Any idea what is causing the first one not to work and how to fix that?

Comment: Please don't post minified code, it's really hard to follow the logic.

Comment: You can't use both together. They both try to set the background color of `document.body`.

Comment: You are correct Barmar, that's why I am trying to find a workaround

Comment: ```corpus.classList.contains("luccious")
    ? (corpus.classList.remove("luccious"),
      (modus.textContent = "TURN OFF THE LIGHTS"),
      (o = "#FFFFFF"),
      (s = "#121212"))
    : (corpus.classList.add("luccious"),
      (modus.textContent = "TURN ON THE LIGHTS"),
      (o = "#121212"),
      (s = "#FFFFFF")),
    (corpus.style.backgroundColor = o),
    (corpus.style.color = s),
    localStorage.setItem("albus", o),
    localStorage.setItem("umbra", s);``` — Good grief. Use an `if` statement.

Comment: What would the workaround do? The document body can only have one background color.

Comment: What do you want it to do? You can't have two different colors, you have to pick one or the other scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer based on comments

In order to set this working we need to do the following

- Define the theme selector, if you use something that has too many colors (Like your current buttons) you will need change button colors (specially font color) each time you switch between light/dark, I will recommend to use a html selector
- Remove those buttons and change it by a selector
- Remove CSS as we are not using the buttons
- When you use light themes change font color in black, when using dark theme change font color white
- Now that we have a selector we need to add an event listener to it (for handling color selector change)
- We can have only one function to achieve the color set in case of load, change the selector or when we don't have a color in our localStorage

```js
const selector = document.querySelector("#themeSelector");

function setBackground(color) {
  localStorage.setItem("colorName", color);
  document.body.style.background = color;
  if (color === "#000000") {
    document.body.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
  } else {
    document.body.style.color = "#000000";
  }
}

if (localStorage.getItem("colorName")) {
  const color = localStorage.getItem("colorName");
  selector.value = color;
  setBackground(color);
} else {
  setBackground(selector.value);
}

selector.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  setBackground(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<label>Choose a theme</label>
<select id="themeSelector">
    <option value='#ECF3F9'>Elegant</option>
    <option value='#F1F9EC'>Modern</option>
    <option value='#F2EBDD'>Classic</option>
    <option value='#FFFFFF'>Default</option>
    <option value='#000000'>Dark</option>
</select>

<p>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Take into account when you use localStorage will last for a long time so if you are testing, first remove it by console before your next try localStorage.removeItem("yourItemId")

Here is the code in codepen, **remember that this is only a guide to achieve what you need:**

https://codepen.io/jwohllk/pen/LYXROjW

Comment: How does this solve the conflict with the second code?

Comment: It almost works, it actually changes the colors but does not remember/saves the background colors

Comment: when I refresh the page, the chosen color disappear

Comment: I was having lunch, I'm working on a final solution keep updated with this